# React stateless component not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, stateless

** Simply aswered Thanks! **

So I'm building a simple 5-page web app with react.

The components are written as stateless as this app is super simple. Everything seems to compile correctly but clicking the menu items changes the route but does not render the component.

** Sorry for not adding an example will do in the future **
My files can be found @ https://github.com/psyfire25/tsl

I am assuming that as nothing changes state or props wise this is the reason the components are not rendering but have no idea how to fix it. In this vein, I have read up on the issue and have tried to implement the suggested fixes but none have helped.

I think there is a simple fix and would really love any help that could be provided would be hugely appreciated.

Many thanks

John

Comment: You should provide a minimal example in your question, not providing a link. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: You may need to use the withRouter middleware in your nav page to get it to link to the browser router you declare in app.  https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

Answer (score 3):

The links you added in the Header.js is incorrect. You are linking to `/Info` but your Route in App.js is `/InfoPage`.

Comment: I knew it was something that simple! Thank you.